# jquery input validation+background color

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, validation

I have an HTML form where I want to add some validation logic. 
In that form i have two input fields, one of them has to get always integer values, while the other one have to get always float values. (first one is items number and other one is total cost).
I want those input fields to change background color to light red if the input value is wrong (float value as item number, for example) and i want to care only for the logic of it, maybe i can guess jQuery can take care of everything else, but I can't find any help on internet on how to get this done without reinventing the wheel.
Does anyone have some hints on how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery Validation? http://goo.gl/Ret4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be talking about form validation

you can write your own code in javascript or jQuery.... or google about form validation you will get tons of result...

for a primer you can check this jQuery validate plugin

```
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
```